# Establishig happens-before relationship in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, happens-before

I know, that there are two way to establish happens-before relationship in java: synchronized blocks and methods, volatile keyword. (if i'm correct, it doesn't work with final fields).
My question is: do atomic variables from concurrent package behave alike? can happens-before be established by them?

Answer (score 6):

yes, they are thread safe and thus you can determine happens/before and after relationships.

AtomicXxxx class operations use volatile, CAS, atomic add or lazy/unordered set. All have some thread safety guarantees but are more light weight than synchronized.

Comment: More specifically, the Javadoc for the java.util.atomic package promises that all AtomicXxxxxxxx objects work like `volatile` variables with extra features.